# Simple scatter plot of paired data of diff lengths, R

Tags: r, plot

I have a set of paired data, x and y, that I want to plot but they are of varying lengths due to some NA values in y. How can I plot x and y only where there is data present in both variables?

```
x      y
10     1
2      3
4      NA # not plotted
10     40
```

Comment: Isn't this what plot() does by default? What exactly is the code you have tried so far and what are the problems you are having?

Answer (score 0):

try - `plot(na.pass(df))` might be useful in this case.